# Add Commas Between Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
[[     date     person  
  0    1/1/2018 john   
  1    1/3/2018 jane   
  2    1/9/2018 john ]
 [     date     person  
  0    2/1/2018 john   
  1    2/3/2018 jane   
  2    2/9/2018 john ]]
```

It is a list of lists, but there are no commas between each element in the list.

Therefore, when attempting to convert the list to a `pandas` `DataFrame`, assertion errors occur because the nested list is technically one column, whereas the target `df` is two columns.

How would I add commas to the nested list or otherwise convert it into a `df` that looks like the one below?

```
date      person
1/1/2018  john
1/3/2018  jane
1/9/2018  john
2/1/2018  john
2/3/2018  jane
2/9/2018  john
```

Comment: List of list of data frames?

Comment: yes, apologies - check my updated question with function code

Comment: just adding commas won't help, you also need to somehow tell pandas that there are 3 rows in each sublist. Am I right?

Comment: there could be any number of rows in the sublists

Comment: pandas accepts a list of dataframes into `pd.concat()`. any way to turn the list of lists of dataframes into a list of dataframes?

Comment: Is there exactly one data frame in the inner list(s) or could there be multiple dfs there?

Comment: Yes, there could be any number of rows, and that needs to be known by Pandas. So the first sublist looks like this `[     date     person  0 1/1/2018 john   1    1/3/2018 jane   2    1/9/2018 john ]`. Just adding commas will not help as far as I understood. You also need to split them into different rows. I hope that is clear now.

Comment: Also, how did you end up with this data structure in the first place? You should probably attack that problem first.

Comment: If the structure is what I think it is, you could try `pd.concat(pd.concat(inner) for inner in df_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to flatten your list and then call `concat`:

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.concat(
        list(chain.from_iterable(data)), ignore_index=True
).set_index('date')
```